# Finding the decade with highest car mileage

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables using MySql; `Owners` and `Cars`, where an owner has a birthdate and the cars have mileage records. The tables look kinda like this:

```
Owners:
+-------+--------------+
| Field | Type         |
+-------+--------------+
| id    | varchar(10)  |
| birth | datetime     |
+-------+--------------+

Cars:
+--------------+-------------+
| Field        | Type        |
+--------------+-------------+
| licenceplate | varchar(6)  |
| mileage      | int(11)     |
| owner        | varchar(10) |
+--------------+-------------+
```

I want a SQL query that provides me with what decade the drivers owning the cars with the highest mileage is. I basically want to group owners born in a certain decade, calculate the average mileage of the cars they are owning, and then present the decade where the average mileage is the highest. I basically want a result like this put into words:

*Car Owners born in the 90s are driving their car the most*

How do I go about it? I've googled and googled, but can't even find how to select decade. Appreciates any help!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Melody Yes, but I don't seem to even be close. tried select max(mileage) as top_mileage, left(birth([year] as varchar(4)), 3) + '0s' as decade from Owners group by left(birth([year] as varchar(4)), 3) order by top_mileage desc

Comment: Jesper please update your question with the extra details in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to combine the two answers that I got to get the average. I got it like this:

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR(YEAR(o.birth) / 10 ) * 10 AS decade, 
    (SUM(mileage) / COUNT(id)) AS avg_mileage_per_driver 
FROM 
    Owners o 
INNER JOIN 
    Cars c 
ON 
    o.id = c.owner 
GROUP BY 
    decade 
ORDER BY 
    decade 
DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that;

```
select FLOOR(YEAR(o.birth) / 10 ) * 10 n, max(c.mileage) as maxmileage 
from owners o inner join cars c ON o.id = c.owner
group by n
order by maxmileage desc
```

Calculate max `mileage` per decade.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really getting the average mileage of ALL car owners born in the 90s, just the average of the individual owner

Comment: And in this case, I need to specifically request the results from people born in the 90s, but I want so that the result presents to me that owners born in the 90s or 80s or 70s are the car owners that drives the most

Comment: Just an observation @Rainman, doesn't this only select the single *highest* mileage driver in each decade (instead of the overall average mileage)? So you could have a single young whipper-snapper from the 90s doing a million miles, whilst everyone else of that age does a thousand miles, but middle-aged guys from the 60s all doing half a million each (doing far more miles overall as a cohort) would be further down the list?

Comment: @Steve, thanks for feedback. You have a good point. Calculating average would give more consistent result. The OP should consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse any syntax errors in the following as I don't have a MySQL environment.

The logic you require is a little bit unclear, but I'm interpreting your question as meaning "for each birth decade, what was the average mileage driven per driver".

**EDIT:** as pointed out by @cdaiga, I should include a `LIMIT` clause to restrict the results to a single row. I've also taken into account @Rainman's answer, and put the extra zero onto the decade in the `SELECT` which is probably better for presentation and readability.

**EDIT 2:** I've adjusted the group-by clause to take account of the error referred to in the comments. I wasn't aware that in MySQL, you can reference columns named in the select clause in the group-by clause.

```
SELECT
    ( (YEAR(birth) DIV 10) * 10 )   AS decade
    ,( SUM(mileage) / COUNT(id) )   AS avg_mileage_per_driver

FROM
    Owners

INNER JOIN
    Cars
    ON Owners.id = Cars.owner

GROUP BY
    decade  -- was:(YEAR(birth) DIV 10)

ORDER BY
    avg_mileage_per_driver DESC

LIMIT 1
```

Comment: He needs the max average milliage, so add LIMIT 1.

Comment: Without realizing it, this is a much better solution since I actually wanted the average. Although, when using this query I get an error-message about the query not being compatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by??

Comment: And I'm not getting the decades from this, just all the occuring years

Comment: @jesper, did you use the `DIV` function for division, not the slash? Div performs integer division, so I really don't see how you could end up with the separate years.

Comment: @Jesper, it would work - my question is whether the `DIV` operator worked, because that operator is specifically designed for integer division (without needing an additional call to `FLOOR`), and I don't see how a proper application of it could have left you with separate years after the group by was applied (since division of a year by ten would generally leave a fractional amount, and `DIV` should not return the fractional amount, which is how it produces the decade). I can only assume you've made a mistake in translation.

Comment: @Jesper, btw I checked the reason you were getting the error: it's because the `GROUP BY` clause should have said `((YEAR(birth) DIV 10) * 10)` to match the expression in the `SELECT` clause. It's a quirk of MySQL apparently.